# SQL query: Finding connected contacts until third degree of depth

Tags: sql, hierarchical-data, greenplum

I am using PostgreSQL 8.2.15 (Greenplum Database 4.3.3.1 build 1), which means that usage of WITH RECURSIVE is not supported.

There is a sample table:

```
select * from reports_Table

reporter spammer
 AAA    BBB
 AAA    CCC
 DDD    CCC
 DDD    BBB
 DDD    EEE
 DDD    FFF
 EEE    DDD
 CCC    AAA
 FFF    DDD
 BBB    AAA
 BBB    CCC
 BBB    DDD
```

Through sql, I am trying to get the list of all reporters as well as spammers connected to AAA, until third degree of depth. In the example above, the result from the query would be:

```
AAA  
BBB  
CCC  
DDD  
FFF  
EEE
```

BBB and CCC are connected directly with AAA therefore 1st degree connection of AAA,
DDD is 2nd degree connection of AAA since it is connected through CCC,
FFF and EEE are 3rd degree connection of AAA since both of them are connected through DDD.

I have managed to get at this point in the query which I think logically it works, but can't go further since can’t seem to understand the occurring syntax error:

```
ERROR: syntax error at or near "WHILE"
```

Most probably the version I am using needs a different syntax for WHILE LOOP, but I can't seem to fix it.

```
/*supported tables*/
CREATE TEMP TABLE variables as
select 1 as first_column, 'AAA'::text as specific_reporter, 3 as degreeNumber

CREATE TEMP TABLE CollectedReporters(
specific_reporter text
);
GO
INSERT INTO CollectedReporters 
select specific_reporter from variables;

/*main query*/
BEGIN
    WHILE (select degreeNumber from variables) >= 1 LOOP
        INSERT INTO CollectedReporters
            SELECT ct.spammer::text as specific_reporter 
                FROM reports_Table ct
                    INNER JOIN CollectedReporters cc ON ct.reporter = cc.specific_reporter::text
                    LEFT JOIN CollectedReporters cc2 ON ct.spammer = cc2.specific_reporter::text
                WHERE cc2.specific_reporter IS NULL;

        UPDATE variables
            SET degreeNumber = degreeNumber - 1;
    END WHILE;
END;

SELECT * FROM  CollectedReporters
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think you should include the occurring error to help us understand the issue. Also you should better format your code using correct indents

Comment: How is it, given your sample data, that `bbb` is "1st degree" and `fff` is a "3rd degree". I don't understand how you are arriving at that conclusion from the sample data.

Comment: I think you can do this efficiently with a recurisve query, `WITH RECURSIVE` in Postgres. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/queries-with.html

Comment: Question is about Greenplum, it does not support `WITH RECURSIVE`

Comment: Here you should clearly state the problem you are solving. Show the input you have and the result you want to achieve. State how to calculate the result. Your example with reporteds/spammers is not informative - it is obvious that you are processing the graph, but is it directed? Do you want to find all the descendants or ascendants of specific node? How do you want to handle cycles?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback guys! I added some more descriptions, hope my problem is clearer now

Comment: you cannot use BEGIN-END in the SQL query. If you need them, you have to write a function. If you are on GPDB 5.0 (dev builds from github), you can also use anonymous code blocks. But here Greenplum things that "BEGIN" is the command to start transaction and "WHILE" should not follow it

Comment: I don't get it.  I don't see how DDD is connected to AAA.  Is this how the data is actually stored?  It looks like a complete mess.  Lastly, the final solution should not be a bunch of insert and update statements as that will take a very long time to execute.

Comment: @0x0FFF, thanks for the input! However, even if I remove BEGIN-END in the query,  same error consists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that you don't understand the database syntax, I'd recommend you to cover [the guide on PG](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/interactive/index.html), it would make the things clearer for you

- First, you can use BEGIN-END construct only inside of the PL/pgSQL functions as it is part of PL/pgSQL language syntax. When used outside of the function, "BEGIN" means beginning of transaction and should be used appropriately
- When you are running some query through your GUI tool, each query should be the correct ANSI SQL query. "while" is not part of ANSI SQL. However, it is part of T-SQL in MSSQL, PL/SQL in Oracle and PL/pgSQL in Postgres
- To use PL/pgSQL in Greenplum version 4.3 and earlier, you have only one option - create a function. In Greenplum version 5.0+ (dev builds from github), you can also use anonymous code blocks in PL/pgSQL

Here is an example of how this might look like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_function (maxlevel int) returns void as $BODY$ 
DECLARE
    level int = 1;
BEGIN

    TRUNCATE CollectedReporters;

    WHILE (level <= maxlevel) LOOP
        RAISE NOTICE 'Processing level %', level;

        INSERT INTO CollectedReporters
            SELECT ct.spammer::text as specific_reporter 
                FROM reports_Table ct
                    INNER JOIN CollectedReporters cc ON ct.reporter = cc.specific_reporter::text
                    LEFT JOIN CollectedReporters cc2 ON ct.spammer = cc2.specific_reporter::text
                WHERE cc2.specific_reporter IS NULL;

        level = level + 1;
    END LOOP;
END;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL VOLATILE;
```